# Do I have the right to sell my lecture notes?

Tags: copyright

I believe my question to be reasonably succinct, 
Am I able to sell other students my lecture notes?
There may well be conditions attached which I am unaware of, though I would not be including any copy pasted material from textbooks or university notes. This is likely a grey area, though I would like to know if this would be possible without breaching copyright law.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is even more succinct. Yes. You wrote it, it's your product.

Comment: ... unless by contract his work product belongs to his employer.  Copyright in the academy seems in practice to be especially muddied by the relationships and contracts asserted by institutions.

Comment: I'm assuming that the person is a person in the class (based on "other students"). It's true that note-taking companies usually hire students, so I am also assuming this student isn't in fact hired to take notes. I suppose there could be some university that forbids students from selling notes taken in class, but then student would have been put on notice about that possibility.

Comment: Could the notes be considered a derivative work?

Comment: No, since lecture notes records the ideas, and not the verbatim expression (unlike a recording). Class lectures are also almost never read from a prepared script (well, in my experience).